# AWS CloudSearch sort by score and text field

Tags: amazon-web-services, sorting, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudsearch, aws-java-sdk

I'm using Amazon's AWS CloudSearch service, and I'm trying to figure out the sort function. I know how to sort by _score, text fields alphabetically, and a combination of _score and int fields, but **I want to sort by _score and a text field**.

I have an index on `title` of type `text`. Here is some sample data:

```
Win the War
A War is Coming
Just a Battle
War of the Wars
Come to the War
```

If I do a search for `war`, I want the following results (simplified score).

#### How do I sort by `(_score desc, title asc)` - score descending followed by title ascending for the results with the same score?

```
Score |  Title
------+-------------------
   2  |  War of the Wars
   1  |  A War is Coming
   1  |  Come to the War
   1  |  Win the War
```

I'm using the Java AWS SDK, so hopefully it's doable with that.

Comment: I've implemented a solution in Java by returning `_all_fields,_score` and using a custom `Comparator` to sort by score then title. I'd really like to know if there's a way to do it purely with the API.

Comment: It's been a while but I am pretty sure you can do this with a custom ranker expression http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/defining-expressions-in-requests.html

Comment: As far as I can tell, the way you've figured out is the only solution.  I thought expressions might help, but you cannot use a text field in a search expression.